# What is the best practice for using git on multiple projects with the same base?

Tags: git

I had a project running on a client which using git as its version control.
After a while, another client wanted the same project with some different features.

Then, I thought of 2 options to manage the new one in git repository.

One, fork the repository, or two, make another branch specific for the new repository.

Since I was new to git, I did both of those to test which was easier to maintain. I, later, went with option two, since it was a lot easier to fix errors in a client then cherry-picked it to another branch (if the errors were in the features that were used in another clients). And also it seems to be easier to switch branch in IDE than have several projects.

However, I am still not convinced that this is the best practice for a several projects since now I have more clients (thus, more branches).

It is really confusing to use branch per feature, and I want to utilize the pull request feature of git. I start to think that it is better to separate projects in their personal repositories.
But if I do that, can I still using a single project in my IDE?

How can I "push" the error fixes to another repository without having to re-code (literally code again, copy paste, or using diff) them in another projects?

Am I doing the right thing?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: They are the same option. A branch and a clone (fork) are no different. You can merge from one to the other, and you can cherry-pick from one to the other.

Comment: Another possibility is to create a library for the shared code and then reuse that library in different projects for each client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> make another branch specific for the new repository.
>      ...
>   cherry-picked it to another branch

This is the right way to work. When using branches you have the option to **share** code between branches. Once you add feature or fix bug you can very easily add it to any desired branch you want.

So branches is the right way to do it.

---

> However, I am still not convinced that this is the best practice for a several projects since now I have more clients (thus, more branches).

- If you wish to use the same code for all your projects/ products you should use branches.
- If you have partial code which you share and each project has its own set of features you should use [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Keep in mind that even if you use different repositories you can still use cherry pick (after adding multiple remotes) between different projects as well.

---

> It is really confusing to use branch per feature

This is the recommended way to work with git.
[Git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) which is one of the most used workflow for git

---

> How can I "push" the error fixes to another repository without having to re-code (literally code again, copy paste, or using diff) them in another projects?

[Add several remotes](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/) to your repository and you can **use** them all on the same time.

Comment: This may not be the solution to my problem (as I explained in my comment in @meagar's answer), but this clearly answered my question with a good and simple explanation. I'm now using several repository forked from the master branch, add those as remotes, and checkout as local branch, and track their own remotes. By doing this I can do branch-per-feature workflow a lot easier since the feature branch will only shown in the respective client repository. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 8):

Version control is not the answer to this, this is not a problem it was never meant to solve. You should have a single codebase for all of your clients, and you should build your features in such a way that they can be turned on and off within that codebase.

Whether that means distilling features out to loadable modules, or building them such that your code is littered with `if/else` statements is up to you, but either solution is better than an explosion of divergent branches. The branch-per-client solution is *barely* better than just copying and pasting the entire codebase to a new directory for each client. If you wind up with a hundred clients and a hundred divergent branches needing to be independently maintained, you're no better off because of version control.

Comment: I understand your thought on this, and yeah, I agree with you by using loadable modules (it is still in development). However, until the new version come out, the running ones should be managed. I am just curious though, is there any better way to do this just with version control. Thank you, by the way. PS: hundreds of clients? Amen to that :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need separated branch for older client not to deliver different features on purpose, but they just started use the older version and you don't want to force them to newer version. Then the branch you have for them is what called *maintenance branch*. I can imagine 2 most obvious ways to manage them:

- bulk merge of older maintenance branches into newer once, cascading them if there are several (v1 into v2, then v2 into v3, then v3 into the master). This relies on assumption that changes to the maintenance branch are minor and well-tested so they are not supposed to break anything in newer branches. This is what git project itself does, for example, (it has only one maintenance branch).
- cherry-pick all changes to needed branches. Then you may use issue tracker to track which changes went where, and it is always a good idea to use `-x` flag to mark that commits were cherrypicked. Usually you develop and stabilize them in master first, but for some cases it is more convenient to use the maintenance branch.

You can start reading [here](http://paulhammant.com/2013/12/04/what_is_your_branching_model/) for example. In general there is no ultimate answer which model to pick.